# Animate UIBarButtonItem with iOS 17 pulse symbol effect not working (without UIImageView)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios17, ios-animations

I'm trying to get the new symbol animation from iOS 17 working for a UIBarButtonItem. The WWDC 2023 video linked to below, "Animate symbols in your app," promises the following:

> [First of all, the new UIKit methods on UIImageView are also available on UIBarButtonItem. This makes it easy to bring your toolbars to life using symbol animations.](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10258?time=813)

Unfortunately, all of the example code accompanying the video only illustrates using UIImageView. I've tried using a UIImageView as a custom view passed to my UIBarButtonItem at initialization as a work-around, but that doesn't work right either.

To be clear, I want to get the effect working on UIBarButtonItem [using the class's function.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/4213093-addsymboleffect)

I made a small demo project using a Storyboard. The code looks like this:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: UIImage.SymbolScale.large)
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "playpause.fill", withConfiguration: config)
        
        let resumeButton =
            UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(sayHello))
        
        resumeButton.addSymbolEffect(.pulse, options: .repeating, animated: true)
        resumeButton.isSymbolAnimationEnabled = true
        
        toolbarItems = [resumeButton]
    }
    
    @objc func sayHello(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("Hello: \(sender)")
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, that should be all I need to get it to work. The button appears and is sized and lined up correctly, but it does not pulse. The symbol effect seems to be dead completely, contrary to what Apple has promised.

Anybody have ideas as to where I've gone wrong? (I'm hoping it's me and not Apple!)

Just for some more context, here is a screenshot of the Storyboard:

[image: Storyboard screenshot]

Here is a screenshot from the simulator:

[image: Simulator screenshot]

I have tried running this both on the simulator and an actual device, with no luck. The button does not pulse.

As a side note, using an image view as a custom view will result in a pulsing button. However, with respect to the other buttons in the toolbar, the button using the custom view neither lines up correctly nor is sized appropriately, *when running on an iOS device.* (Strangely, it will look fine in the Simulator!) This seems to be a known and longstanding issue that goes all the way back to iOS 11 and apparently has no easy answers. I'd rather abandon the whole effect than trying some kind of kludge to resize and realign an image view.

Thank you.

Comment: I played around with your code and couldn't get it to work either. However, I had no issues with size or alignment when creating a UIBarButtonItem with a UIImageView as a custom view. It was exactly the same size and alignment as creating the UIBarButtonItem directly with the image or a system item.

Comment: What I've found is that the size and alignment look fine in the simulator, but not on a device. I have only run it on my iPhone SE (3rd generation). Maybe it will look fine on another device, but not my iPhone? Please let me know if you can. I'll edit my post, based on your answer.

Comment: I see it now. I had just tested on an iOS 17.2 iPhone 15 Pro simulator and the two images were the same size. But my iOS 17.2 iPhone 13 Pro shows the image view image just a bit smaller. Strange.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I have edited my post to reflect that detail. On my phone, the image looks slightly smaller. I've tried several things, but can't fix that. It is also not centered along the X-axis, compared to other UIBarButtonItems in the toolbar.  If I rotate the phone, it is even more misaligned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED

I don't think this is at all obvious, but if you save a handle to the bar button item as an instance variable and then start the animation only after the view appears, the effect is visible.

Here is the working code:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var button: UIBarButtonItem?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: UIImage.SymbolScale.large)
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "playpause.fill", withConfiguration: config)
        
        let resumeButton =
            UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(sayHello))
        
        // The animation cannot be started yet…
        button = resumeButton
        
        toolbarItems = [resumeButton]
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        // SOLVED: Start the animation after the view appears.
        button?.addSymbolEffect(.pulse, options: .repeating, animated: true)
    }
    
    @objc func sayHello(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("Hello: \(sender)")
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to use `viewIsAppearing` instead of `viewDidAppear`. It avoids the tiny delay though it may not be noticeable. Interesting find. I suggest filing a bug report with Apple showing what you've found. This solution shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I gave that a try. For this particular pulsing animation, it seems to make no appreciable difference. But, just as a rule of thumb, I think your suggestion is a good one. Putting it in `viewIsAppearing` seems to be the right idea, generally speaking.

Comment: P.S. Since, like me, you've been around a while, you may be interested to know that `viewDidAppear:` seems to be required when coding this in Objective-C. I find it strange that `viewIsAppearing(_:)` works for the effect in Swift, but not Objective-C, but that's what I'm getting. I put some sample code here: https://pastebin.com/HC3g6A8v

Comment: I just replicated this in Objective-C and it's working just fine for me when adding the symbol effect in `viewIsAppearing:`.

Comment: How odd! I still can't get that to work. Oh well, I'm not all that concerned. Maybe I'll get to the bottom of what I'm doing differently. In any case, the major problem is solved. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I even copied your pastebin code exactly and it worked just fine after renaming `viewDidAppear` to `viewIsAppearing` (and the call to `super`). Maybe you had a typo in the name for `viewIsAppearing`. It worked in the sim and a real device.

Comment: I'm using autocomplete to type out the method. Just for kicks, I deleted the app from the simulator, cleaned the build, quit Xcode, deleted the Derived Data, and then restarted and ran the app. Still broken! I'm going to let my sanity recoup for now and maybe get back to debugging this (on my machine!), should the spirit move me. So strange! Thanks, though :-)